# Cannot load Java GDAL native library in web application

Tags: java, c++, maven, shared-libraries, native

I'm using GDAL library java as a dependency in Java web application with Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It contains a jar file and runs the native codes in C++ underneath which I had to install from packages in Centos. All these shared libraries are installed in

```
ls -l /usr/lib/java/gdal/
total 1380
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  23288 Feb 14  2016 libgdalconstjni.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  23288 Feb 14  2016 libgdalconstjni.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  23288 Feb 14  2016 libgdalconstjni.so.1.18.4
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 226696 Feb 14  2016 libgdaljni.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 226696 Feb 14  2016 libgdaljni.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 226696 Feb 14  2016 libgdaljni.so.1.18.4
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 136760 Feb 14  2016 libogrjni.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 136760 Feb 14  2016 libogrjni.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 136760 Feb 14  2016 libogrjni.so.1.18.4
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  73816 Feb 14  2016 libosrjni.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  73816 Feb 14  2016 libosrjni.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  73816 Feb 14  2016 libosrjni.so.1.18.4
```

However, the web application cannot link as it has a problem to link libraries, although what I can see from class loader of Java is:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

which contains the /usr/lib folder.

The error from the GDAL java when I invoke a GDAL API (it does not have error if I don't invoke GDAL's methods so other methods still work, Web application can run normally) is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1()J
at org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1(Native Method) ~[gdal-1.11.1.jar:na]
at org.gdal.osr.SpatialReference.<init>(SpatialReference.java:117) ~[gdal-1.11.1.jar:na]
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, tried to find lots of resources but no help as I want to deploy this as a Web application in Tomcat server. I could make it work when setting in NetBeans IDE with JVM option

```
-Djava.library.path="/usr/lib/java/gdal/"
```

but I know this is not what web application can run.

Comment: If I try to load a shared object manually with:
System.load("/usr/lib/java/gdal/libgdalconstjni.so"); 

it does not accept to load from the beginning

 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/java/gdal/libogrjni.so already loaded in another classloader

Answer (score 0):

I could do this with a great help from this blog http://fahdshariff.blogspot.de/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html

```
Option 2: Add path to usr_paths
Instead of having to re-evaluate the entire java.library.path and sun.boot.library.path as in Option 1, you can instead append your path to the usr_paths array. This is shown in the following code:
/**
* Adds the specified path to the java library path
*
* @param pathToAdd the path to add
* @throws Exception
*/
public static void addLibraryPath(String pathToAdd) throws Exception{
    final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
    usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

    //get array of paths
    final String[] paths = (String[])usrPathsField.get(null);

    //check if the path to add is already present
    for(String path : paths) {
        if(path.equals(pathToAdd)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    //add the new path
    final String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
    newPaths[newPaths.length-1] = pathToAdd;
    usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
}
```